# how to do form_for with dynamic, multi-level hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a class with dynamic content.  I initialize it in the new method in the controller:

```
def new
  @person = Person.new(:info => {:first_name => "Joe", :last_name => "Smith"})
end
```

Now, disregard the fact that I'm manually coordinating the structure of :info between my controller and form (I have a meta configuration stored in another class, I'm simplifying this to seek abstract help), how do I set up a field for first_name and last_name?  This fails:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
    <% f.text_field :info[:first_name] %>
<% end %>
```

It fails with

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :info do |ff|
    <% ff.text_field :first_name %>
   <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: @breno-preucchi this works on new and create (i can see the data), but not on edit. on edit, the params are there in the HTML, but the value is missing so the input box shows up as blank.  inspection shows this:
    <input type="text" name="person[info][first name]" 
but it appears blank (no val set), any ideas why?

Comment: and if i enter a new first name, it does go to the database, so it works on update too.

Comment: O database can't save hash values. Probably you have a attribute info as string in your database. To do that you need serialize this hash. I will edit my post to add a example for that.